# Unit Test for Controller Scenarios with int as -1 in C# ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I'm currently diving into unit testing for an ASP.NET Core controller, and I've stumbled upon an interesting scenario. In my project, the `StatusId` property in the `UpdateUser` model is declared as `int`, but its corresponding database type is `tinyint`. The API accepts a `StatusId` value of `-1` under certain conditions.

---

Here's a snippet of the relevant code:

```
public static class Constant
{
    public static readonly int[] AdminRoleId = new int[] { 1, 2 };
}

public class UpdateUserBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class UpdateUser : UpdateUserBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int StatusId { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
// ... Controller code ...

public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateUser(UpdateUser user)
{
    if (!Constant.Constant.AdminRoleId.Contains(UserRoleId))
        user.StatusId = 0; // If it's 0, the status won't be changed

    int result = await _service.UpdateUser(user);.

    return result switch
    {
        > 0 => Ok(),
        _ => BadRequest("Update Failed.")
    };
}
```

---

I'm particularly interested in understanding how I should approach unit testing when the `StatusId` is set to `-1`. Given the difference in data types (C# `int` vs. database `tinyint`), are there any considerations or best practices I should keep in mind? Should I specifically test the scenario where `StatusId` is `-1`?

Your guidance and insights would be immensely helpful as I navigate this testing process. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good idea to add test cases in the transition zones where values may cause one kind of behaviour on one side, and different behaviour on the other.

Such values are often called *boundary values* because they populate the boundary between two regimes.

In this example, a `tinyint` is a single byte holding values between `0` and `255` (both included), whereas a .NET `int` (a 32-bit signed integer) spans a vastly larger range - to both sides.

Thus, it's a good idea to test with *at least* the values `-1` and `0`, but also with `255` and `256`.

All that said, why not change the declaration of `StatuId` to be a `byte`?

Comment: I appreciate your guidance. Concerning unit testing, the project enforces a specific logic during user creation or update, allowing only statusId values of 1 or 2. 

Given this business rule, would it be advisable to focus the unit tests on scenarios directly aligned with these permitted values (1 and 2)? I'm curious whether explicitly covering transition zones like -1, 0, 255, and 256 aligns with the project's specific use cases and would contribute meaningfully to the testing suite.

Comment: @loosamwong These sound like separate concerns (both valid). If the business logic only allows 1 and 2, it'd be relevant to test these scenarios. It's *also* important, however, to test what happens in the 'negative space', so to speak. Technically, `StatusId` can take any value between -2147483648 and 2147483647. You can't possibly test all of those, but it will typically be helpful to ascertain that the system behaves correctly for elect values. Typical values a tester would choose might be those min and max values, -1, 0, 255, 256, and so on. If only 1 and 2 are valid, I'd test 3 as well.